# Informatica Cloud - Picking up files from SFTP and inserting records in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, informatica, informatica-cloud

Our objective is as follows

a) Pick up a file "Test.csv" from a Secure FTP location.

b) After picking up the file we need to insert the contents of the file into an object in Salesforce.

I created the following connection for the Remote SFTP (the location which will contain "Test.csv")

[image]

Step 1

This is as shown below

[image]

Step 2

Then I started to build a Data Synchronization Task as below

[image]

What we want is for the Informatica Cloud to connect to the secure FTP location and extract the contents from a .csv from that location into our object in Salesforce.

But as you can see in Step 2, it does not allow me to choose .csv from that remote location.

Instead the wizard prompts me to choose a file from a local directory (which is my machine ...where the secure agent is running) and this is not what I want

What should I do in this scenario ?

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

You can write a UNIX script to transfer the file to your secure agent and then use informatica to read the file. Although, I have never tried using sftp in cloud, I have used cloud  and I do know that all files are tied up to the location of the secure agent( either server or local computer) .

Answer (score 0):

The local directory is used for template files. The idea is that you set up the task using a local template and then IC will connect to the FTP site when you actually run the task.

The Informatica video below shows how this works at around 1:10:

This video explains how it works at around 1:10:

http://videos.informaticacloud.com/2FQjj/secure-ftp-and-salesforececom-using-informatica-cloud/

Answer (score 0):

Can you elaborate the Secure agent OS as in Windows or Linux.

For Windows environment you will have to call the script using WINSCP or CYGWIN utility I recommend the former.

For Linux the basic commands in script should work.